# WP Memory Limit - Should I dedicate all my RAM to this setting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 6GB Ram with my host - in woocommerce system status it says this is the amount of ram your wordpress site can use at one time?

I'm confused with this - should I set this setting to 6000M or not - don't I want all my RAM dedicated to my woocommerce site as it is 98% woocom pages.

Setting from wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3072M');
```

This is my current setting.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr **3072M is far too high** for this setting.

It's hard to answer this question without more information about your server environment.  Is the server dedicated to your WordPress / Woo instance or are you sharing it with others?  Is your MySQL instance running on this same server with your WordPress instance?

You definitely don't want to give all your RAM, or even half of it, to WordPress this way. Why not? Because it's not a shared limit. When your site is busy you have multiple web server processes running, and they each obey the limits you give.  If you give them all half your RAM and they take it, your server will  [thrash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), and your web site will work poorly if at all. Thrashing servers sometimes experience hard crashes. You don't want that.

In any case `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` can't set memory limits to exceed the [php memory limits](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your system. That's probably why your current ludicrously high setting of `3072M` hasn't already brought your site to its knees.

There are separate limits here because some servers use PHP for other things than WordPress.

My suggestion: be very careful messing with this number. Make conservative changes.  If you're getting php memory exhaustion errors from WordPress, increase this limit (and the php memory limit) slowly and sparingly until things start to work.

Install a plugin to monitor memory. Here is one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/server-ip-memory-usage/

Keep an eye on your web server error log to see if you're routinely getting memory exhaustion errors.

Comment: its a bluehost cloud site business pro shared i thought if I increased the memory it would make my cron jobs with wp all import run faster as I import many products weekly about (200,000) what should I set it too? http://cloud.bluehost.com/products/cloud-sites

Comment: Your assumption that more RAM will speed your import is unjustified. PHP programs like WordPress / Woo, especially ones that crank through large batches of data, are designed to limit their RAM usage by processing only one or a few items at a time. Those programs are designed to run in systems limited to around 100Megabytes. Adding RAM doesn't make that faster. Plus, as I mentioned, the php memory limit probably governs this RAM usage. **Leave this parameter unchanged from the default unless you know you must change it because you get memory exhaustion errors.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how memory intensive your site is. Try logging a few calls to `memory_get_peak_usage()` to see. I wouldn't assign more than 128 MiB of memory by default. You don't want a bug in the code to eat all of your server's available RAM.